# Replace NA with mean based on row subset matching another column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data where each row contains a person's gender and weight (in lbs):

```
genders <- c("FEMALE", "FEMALE", "FEMALE", "FEMALE", "FEMALE", "MALE", "MALE", "MALE", "MALE")
weights <- c(110.0, 120.0, 112.0, NA, NA, 190.0, 202.0, 195.0, NA)

df <- data.frame(gender=genders, weight=weights)
df
#   gender weight
# 1 FEMALE    110
# 2 FEMALE    120
# 3 FEMALE    112
# 4 FEMALE     NA
# 5 FEMALE     NA
# 6   MALE    190
# 7   MALE    202
# 8   MALE    195
# 9   MALE     NA
```

For every row that has an NA in the `weight` column, I would like to replace / impute the NA with the `weight` mean, but the mean should be calculated using only the rows that match the same `gender` value as the row with the NA.

Specifically, rows 4 and 5 have a `gender` of FEMALE and `weight` of NA. I want to replace the NA with the mean `weight` computed over the subset of rows that match the `gender` of FEMALE. In this case, the mean would be (110+120+112)/3=114.0 from the other rows 1, 2, and 3.

Likewise, I want to replace the NA in row 9 with the mean of the weights for MALE `gender`.

I tried the following command, but it replaced the NA with the mean weight over **all** users across both genders, which is not what I want.

```
df$weight[is.na(df$weight)] <- mean(subset(df, gender=df$gender)$weight, na.rm=T)
df
#   gender   weight
# 1 FEMALE 110.0000
# 2 FEMALE 120.0000
# 3 FEMALE 112.0000
# 4 FEMALE 154.8333
# 5 FEMALE 154.8333
# 6   MALE 190.0000
# 7   MALE 202.0000
# 8   MALE 195.0000
# 9   MALE 154.8333
```

I searched other questions, but they are not quite the same problem as mine:

"[Replace NA with mean matching the same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695021/replace-na-with-mean-matching-the-same-id)"

"[How to replace NA with mean by subset in R (impute with plyr?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322773/how-to-replace-na-with-mean-by-subset-in-r-impute-with-plyr)"

"[How to replace NA values in a table *for selected columns*? data.frame, data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379081/how-to-replace-na-values-in-a-table-for-selected-columns-data-frame-data-tab)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `ave()` with `replace()` (or standard manual replacement).

```
df$weight <- with(df, ave(weight, gender,
    FUN = function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

which gives

> ```
>   gender   weight
> 1 FEMALE 110.0000
> 2 FEMALE 120.0000
> 3 FEMALE 112.0000
> 4 FEMALE 114.0000
> 5 FEMALE 114.0000
> 6   MALE 190.0000
> 7   MALE 202.0000
> 8   MALE 195.0000
> 9   MALE 195.6667
> ```

Comment: Thank you. Simple answer without extra packages. Just what I was looking for. That `ave()` function looks very powerful.

Answer (score 5):

You can group your data frame by `gender` and then calculate the average of weight and replace the `NA` with `ifelse` statement, in `dplyr`, it could be:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
      group_by(gender) %>% 
      mutate(weight = ifelse(is.na(weight), mean(weight, na.rm = T), weight))

# Source: local data frame [9 x 2]
# Groups: gender [2]

#  gender   weight
#  <fctr>    <dbl>
# 1 FEMALE 110.0000
# 2 FEMALE 120.0000
# 3 FEMALE 112.0000
# 4 FEMALE 114.0000
# 5 FEMALE 114.0000
# 6   MALE 190.0000
# 7   MALE 202.0000
# 8   MALE 195.0000
# 9   MALE 195.6667
```

Comment: The new `coalesce` function fits well here.

Comment: @alistaire Looks very useful and handy.

Answer (score 2):

Using base R this appears to be what you're looking for:

```
df$weight[df$gender=="FEMALE" & is.na(df$weight)] <- mean(df$weight[df$gender=="FEMALE"], na.rm=TRUE)
df$weight[df$gender=="MALE" & is.na(df$weight)] <- mean(df$weight[df$gender=="MALE"], na.rm=TRUE)

> df
  gender   weight
1 FEMALE 110.0000
2 FEMALE 120.0000
3 FEMALE 112.0000
4 FEMALE 114.0000
5 FEMALE 114.0000
6   MALE 190.0000
7   MALE 202.0000
8   MALE 195.0000
9   MALE 195.6667
```

Comment: This is very manual approach. How would they use is for more than two groups? See in comments a more generalized approach

Comment: Is there a way to do this without hard-coding "FEMALE" and "MALE"? The data in a column could have dozens of unique values.

Comment: @DavidArenburg good point. It looks like Richard Scriven's approach is better and works in the case where there's several unique values.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using `na.aggregate` from `zoo`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'gender', we apply the `na.aggregate` to 'weight' to replace the NA elements with the `mean` value. By default, the `na.aggregate` return the `mean`, but we can also change the `FUN` argument to get `median` or `sum` etc.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df)[, weight := na.aggregate(weight) , by = gender]
```

---

Or with `ave` from `base R`

```
with(df, ave(weight, gender, FUN = na.aggregate))
#[1] 110.0000 120.0000 112.0000 114.0000 114.0000 190.0000 202.0000 195.0000 195.6667
```